# What is "a little armchair psychology"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I've been reading about "Calabar beans":

> **Its chemical composition, along with a little armchair psychology,**
> may explain why the plant had such different effects on the poor souls
> facing a trial by ordeal. A person who knew they were innocent might
> chew the bean quickly and swallow it with pride, ingesting a quick dose
> that would cause them to vomit before the bean could do more damage.
> A guilty party, dreading death, might take tiny, slow bites. Ironically,
> this attempt to prolong their own life would only hasten their death by
> delivering a gradual, well-digested dose of poison.

I feel confused for the meaning of "a little armchair psychology" in the above the sentence.

"**Its chemical composition, along with a little armchair psychology**,
may explain why the plant had such different effects on the poor souls
facing a trial by ordeal."

= **Based on its chemical composition and a little general psychology**, we may know
why the plant had such different effects on the poor souls facing a trial by ordeal.

I'm not sure what I think is right.
Could you explain what "a little armchair psychology" means more easily?

Comment: I understand it as the advice that is given by such a person. They may have a little knowledge (rather than your "no known background knowledge") but it is superficial and so is the advice.

Comment: This question about armchair psychology is relevant: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/394687/origin-of-armchair-x

Comment: You seem to already know the meaning of the phrase, which leaves it rather unclear what exactly you are asking.